# Cannot instantiate the type List

Tags: java, list, swt

I am getting the erorr as "Cannot instantiate the type List" when I use the below code:

```
list = new List(floatShell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
            | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

But this example is given here: https://gist.github.com/Suxiaogang/6311176d2c5b9a8d1867

What is the mistake that I have made?

Answer (score 1):

You probably did `import java.util.List;` when you need to `import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;`

Comment: Thank you. 
But now I have another error "The import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List collides with another import statement" as I am also using List for normal lists

Comment: In this case, you have to decide which one to import (the one you are using most often in your code) and always address the other one(s) directly, for example if you used `import java.util.List;`, then for your other List you would need to write `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List list;` (in your declaration) and `list = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List(floatShell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
            | SWT.V_SCROLL);`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this `import` statement:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;
```

If you don't have it, provide it, but if you have another `List` class already imported (from a different package, `import java.util.List` for example), you can instantiate this one with its fully-qualified class name:

```
list = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List(floatShell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
        | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

Comment: I had to add cast to it. Thank you